# User comments plugin on my website using Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

is it possible to add some kind of comments form for users of my website based on `Google Analytics`?

Does `Google Analytics` have such a functionality? Or maybe some third party plugins could do it?

Thank you!

Comment: What you mean? Do an example, pls

Comment: I want my users to be able to leave comments about my website.

Comment: I know I can make a modal form and make it possible. But I wonder, maybe there is a ready to use plugin for it provided by google anatytics?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some confusion about what Google Analytics does. It is a tracking system, it has nothing to do with the functionality of the site, such as leaving a comment.

So to remove any doubt the answer is **no**, it does not provide any plugin to do what you want.